# Google Script - Sidebar button keeps opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications, form-submit

I'm creating an extremely basic script to assist me in one of my google spreadsheets.

I've successfully got a sidebar showing, with a few buttons (which function). However, whenever I click on one of those buttons, it also opens up a new tab, with a URL something like: "https://n-lx3mdv5ls3mdgglsq226llilxd2m4owxy72y3fy-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?"

Even if the button is left without any functionality, this still occurs.

Here's an example of the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->

    <style>
    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <form>
       <div class="block" id="buttons">
          <button id="unindent">Unindent</button>
          <button id="indent">Indent</button>
          <button id="asdgdgasg">Test</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I stop this new tab from opening every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `<button>` type, if not specified defaults to `type=submit`. So, The form automatically submits the data to the server. This is not preferable in a iframe.

#### Solution:

- Explicitly specify button type as button. `<button type='button'`>
- Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent automatic form submission.

#### References:

- [Button#Default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type)
- [Sample Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

Comment: By your answer, I could notice that my answer might confuse users. So I would like to delete my answer. Thank you. And I think that your answer should be upvoted.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I found <input type="button> also avoids the issue.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for the comment. From my experiences, when I saw this question, I remembered that. If that information might be useful even for just a bit, I would like to undelete it.

Answer (score 2):

When I saw your issue, I thought that this is due to `<form>`. So I proposed the following modifications.

1. Modify `<form>` to `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">`.
2. Modify `<base target="_top">` to `<base target="_self">`.
3. Remove `<base target="_top">`.

#### Note:

- I think that [@TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825392/7108653) is more useful information.

#### References:

- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [The Document Base URL element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: Your answer <base target="_self"> solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872906/submit-form-with-apps-script/54887387#54887387 - would you like to enter an answer?

Comment: @user61629 Thank you for your comment. When I saw the thread just now, it had already been resolved. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.