# Close the created page on sidebar form submit

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

[image]

I have a template in a side bar with a form using the html service attached to a sheet (screenshot). In my template, when I thick the submit button it activates:

```
        function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {

            google.script.run.processRowPopupHTML(formObject); // the output from form goes to processDocBuildHtml
            google.script.host.close();

        }
```

This works fine as far as sending the text in the textarea to the server side. But when this happens I  get a big blank screen that looks like:

[image]

which I then have to close. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: What does `processRowPopupHTML() ` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script - Sidebar button keeps opening a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825069/google-script-sidebar-button-keeps-opening-a-new-tab)