# Submit Form with apps script

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm having the problem described in [Google Script - Sidebar button keeps opening a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825069/google-script-sidebar-button-keeps-opening-a-new-tab). I initially was using:

```
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

But ran into a problem when the submit was creating a new tab as described in that question. I tried to change to the approach discussed in the post:

```
<button type='button'>
```

but this results in an unclickable button:

[image]

Now I've changed it back to :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now I can close the form on clicking but the form does not seem to submit anything to the server side when I check the logs I don't see anything submitted on the server side.

How can I get this working and submit the form? The Entire template is below and should be freestanding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top" />
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('forms');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close())
          .processRowPopupHTML(formObject);
      }

      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Sent!</a>';
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <div id="texts"></div>

      <div>
        <label for="optionList">Click me</label>
        <select
          id="optionList"
          ondblclick="addText(event)"
          name="optionList"
          size="5"
        >
        </select>
      </div>

      <br />

      <br />

      <div>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div id="textboxes"></div>

      <div id="insert"></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>


    <div id="output"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
    <link
      href="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script>
      //  var canned = <?= canned ?>; //PASSED IN JSON
      var mycannedObj = ['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi'];

      function addText(event) {
        var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
        document.getElementById('message').value +=
          ' ' + targ.textContent || targ.innerText + ' ';
      }

      function buildOptionList(options, elementId) {
        var list = $('#' + elementId);

        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          console.log(options[i]);
          list.append(
            '<option value="' +
              options[i].toLowerCase() +
              '">' +
              options[i] +
              '</option>'
          );
        }
      }

      (function() {
        buildOptionList(mycannedObj, 'optionList');
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

After changing code to :

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processRowPopupHTML(formObject);

and clicking the button I again got a new tab opened with:

```
https://n-g6b................tas763ea-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?optionList=hi&message=+hi
```

The console shows:

[image]

I do see:

```
[19-02-25 17:05:06:900 PST] {optionList=hi, message= hi}
```

In the logs, as expected, so that is good. But how do I stop the tab from opening up?

Comment: As with your last nearly identical question, you are assigning the **result of** a function call as the success handler, instead of the **function** *to be called*. There's also [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813537/close-the-created-page-on-sidebar-form-submit) - what's the difference between it and this? Or are you just re-asking?

Comment: @tehhowch , I decided to clean up and summarize the last question because there were several changes to my code and I felt it might be getting hard for others to follow. I also reworked the template so it is now complete and standalone with extraneous code to this question removed. That way others can try it out without modification.

Comment: @tehhowch, regarding " you are assigning the result of a function call as the success handler, instead of the function to be called. " - Do you mean change google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).processRowPopupHTML(formObject); to google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processRowPopupHTML(formObject); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

`forms` is not a valid css selector or a node name. So, `preventDefault()` is never attached to the `form` submit event on `load`.

#### Solution:

Replace

```
document.querySelectorAll('forms');
```

with

```
document.querySelectorAll('form');
```

#### References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you receive the "unsafe navigation" warning because of additional unspecified arguments passed from `withSuccessHandler` to `google.script.host.close`. When providing success handlers, if they are not your own function (i.e. you know exactly what arguments they take and use), you are best off accessing them in an anonymous function:

```
...
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close())
  .withFailureHandler(unhandledServersideException => console.log(unhandledServersideException))
  .foo();
...
```

If you don't want to use arrow syntax in the HTML files, that would be

```
withSuccessHandler(function () { google.script.host.close(); })
```

In this manner you ensure that whatever the output of `foo` is, it is not passed to `google.script.host.close`

Comment: Thanks I tried this and there was no change - The same error persists. I did change  <base target="_top"> to  <base target="_self"> and this stops the popup tab, so overall it's now working.