# Get return value from a modal dialog page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I look at severals tutorials and pages about how to open a modal dialog with GAS.
My purpose is quite simple. I want to open a dialog box with a field. The user enter a value and I get it in the next steps of my script.

In my spreadsheet, I have

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('datePaiementDlg');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');

}
function returnDatePaiementDlg( values)
{
  Logger.log(values);
  Browser.msgBox(values);
}
```

The HTML page is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
   <input type="date" name="datePaiement"/>

   <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="action" onclick="form_data()" />
   <input type="button" value="Fermer"  class="action" onclick="closeIt()" />
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
<script>
function form_data(){
  var values = $("input[name=datePaiement]).val();
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(closeIt)
  .returnDatePaiementDlg(values);
};
function closeIt(){
google.script.host.close();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I run the openDialog() function from a menu item in a Google Spreadsheet.
When I click the Submit button, a new blank page is opened. If I go back to my spreadsheet page, the dialog box is still opened (it should be closed, no ?)

Then, an other question : I want to use the value entered by the user after the showModalDialog(). But I can't understand how, since the "Submit" button call an other function ( returnDatePaiementDlg()). How can I make the "link" ?

I forgot something... what ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script - Sidebar button keeps opening a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825069/google-script-sidebar-button-keeps-opening-a-new-tab)

Comment: Welcome. Question posts should only one question, otherwise they are considered too broad.

Comment: You need to `preventDefault()`. See sample script in the duplicate question link

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function askAQuestion() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<select id="sel1" onchange="sendChoice()">'
  html+='<option value="no Choice">Make a Choice</option>';
  html+='<option value="Sheet1">Sheet1</option>';
  html+='<option value="Sheet2">Sheet2</option>';
  html+='<option value="Sheet3">Sheet3</option>';
  html+='</select>';
  html+='<script>function sendChoice() { var choice=document.getElementById(\'sel1\').value;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).displayChoice(choice);}console.log(\'My Code\');</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Make a Choice');
}

function displayChoice(choice) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(choice);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! But I must admit it's not very convenient to write the html page like this :). I read posts about the input item or the submit process that may interfere. But what was wrong ?

Comment: @TheMaster : yes my problem looks like the post you mentionned. But the solution does not work for me.

Comment: @Rubén : ok, I found the solution since javascript can't be "stopped" while the dialog box is opened. I chained the processes.

Comment: No it's not convenient.  But for a quick example it takes up a lot less space and it is possible especially if you keep the JavaScript simple and short.